# multiple selective sortable lists (1 master and 2 subs)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I haven't seen any examples of selective sortables:

[A: one master list]
[B: one sublist]
[C: another sublist]

---

**Conditions:**

1. B and C can transfer to A
2. A can only transfer to B the elements that came from B (the same applies to C)
3. B and C cannot transfer between eachother

---

**Example Structure:**

```
<ul class="A"></ul>    
<ul class="B">
   <li class="child-B" />
   <li class="child-B" />
   <li class="child-B" />
</ul>
<ul class="C">
   <li class="child-C" />
   <li class="child-C" />
   <li class="child-C" />
</ul>
```

---

I've tried applying sortable to the lists and trying to dynamically alter the connectWith afterwards (they'd all be able to connect to A), but no luck.  Here's one of my attempts ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/aCEPY/)).  I also tried putting '.master,.sub' as the initial connectWith, but it allows cross sharing.

I think the second looping is updating the sortable's connectWith, so I'm stuck.  Any ideas?

Comment: It would be nice if there was a way to reject an item in the `receive` event, but there does not seem to be a built in way to do so.

Comment: @James: Isn't that what cancel does?

Comment: @JeffB everything I read said it didn't work in receive.  Guess I should have tested it because it looks like from Goran's answer that it does in fact work exactly as I had wanted.  A big ugly on the animation but functional.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I agree.  I read documentation and heard some of the same things, maybe there are browser bugs, but Goran's answer works for me so far.  That's why I tried to do connectWith initially, instead of canceling, it would just never start if the list wasn't right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the first time that I've played around with `sortable` (with a bit of reading from jqueryui.com) but I think this should do the trick. You can see it in action at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/das4B/1/)

HTML:

```
<ul class="master"></ul>

<ul class="sub a">
    <li class="a">Foo</li>
    <li class="a">Boo</li>
</ul>
<ul class="sub b">
    <li class="b">Bar</li>
    <li class="b">Baz</li>
</ul>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // create sortables
    $( ".master,.sub" ).sortable({
       connectWith: ".master,.sub",
       revert: true,
       receive: function(event, ui) {

           // only perform for sub drop downs
           if ($(this).hasClass('sub'))
           {
               // if the item doesn't have the matching sub class
               if (!$(this).hasClass($(ui.item).attr('class')))
               {
                   // cancel the sortable
                   $(ui.sender).sortable('cancel');
               }
           }
       }
    }).disableSelection(); 
});
```

This example basically performs the validation on receiving the item, and if it doesn't pass, it cancels the move.

Hope it's what you're looking for.

Comment: That will definitely work - still curious why there would be a setter for connectWith, if it doesn't do anything.  The other thing I'd like is to do the validation up front.  It seems like the animation tries to put it into place and then once it settles, it decides it shouldn't go there.  It should figure out it shouldn't go there before it tries to settle

Comment: Wish I could tell you why, I just happened to have read a little on jQuery UI earlier that day. According to [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/), the `connectWith` property is only applied to sortables, and not the individual items within a sortable, so some form of custom validation is needed. You could probably try fiddling around with the other events listed on that link, but `receive` was the best I could find.

Comment: And a good find it was.  Normally, I'd go into the base code and check what's going on and either modify,replace, or add a plugin; but i didn't have time - so I appreciate the extra set of eyes and the help.